# javascript with multiple slides within the same div container

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have created multiple html slideshows with jquery under different categories. For example, Under 'POOLS' category I have a slideshow for POOLS with 3 images. Under 'DRIVEWAYS'category I have made a slideshow or 3 images of Driveways. 
I have it set up where there is a container at the top (for slideshows) and I have also different thumbnails of each category below the container. I want to be able to link each thumbnail to each slideshow. I need these slideshows to appear in the top container everytime I click on a thumbnail the slideshow will appear in the container (with its own controls).
Can someone tell me an easier/quicker way to call these slideshows. I'm just learning Javascript and I'd like to know if there is an option or a way to call these html slideshows in the top container. I have searched for days and I'm not sure if I am searching the right key words. This could be something simple but it's driving me crazy trying to figure it out.
Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: You need to put your code in question.

Comment: Here's the thing, I really don't have code...that's where I am stuck. I'm not sure where to go from there. I created "Interiors" page that has a div container that I want my slideshows to appear in. Do I use a function to call these slideshows? or can I just reference with a link? (I tried using 'url' but nothing happened). Can you point me to the right direction where I can get the right info? I do not want a slider that slides automatically with the images at the bottom. I need each thumbnail to open up the slideshows in the div container (at top) respectively. THANKS SO MUCH!!!!

Comment: Something like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/5mzsrtte/2/)?

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help! I will try this code and hopefully it will solve my issue...:-)

Comment: If it solves please comment here so that I'll post it as answer.

Comment: I will try it tonight and I will definitely let you know if it works. sorry about that.

Comment: You don't need to say sorry. Try the solution and if it helped you then please mark it as answer.

Comment: The slide is not showing in the sliderContainer div that I created. I am not sure where I need to place my html link for each thumbnail pic. I am also not sure if I need another div container to hold my sliderContainer...Can you show me an example where I would place/call my html slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="EX2contentwrapper">
<div id="sliderContainer">
<iframe id="myframe" src="" width="1000" height="400"></iframe>
</div><!--End of slidecontainer-->  

<div id="EX2thumbnailpicsbox">  

    <!--first row of images-->
    <div id="thumbs">
    <img id="EX2-Poolspic" class="thumbs" src="http://i101.photobucket.com/albums/m55/ladybytesjdb/ACsite/EX2_Poolspic_zps6a6a33d1.jpg">
    <img id="EX2-Patiospic" class="thumbs" src="http://i101.photobucket.com/albums/m55/ladybytesjdb/ACsite/EX2_Patiospic_zps91f4842c.jpg">
    <img id="EX2-Stairspic" class="thumbs" src="http://i101.photobucket.com/albums/m55/ladybytesjdb/ACsite/EX2_Stairspic_zps53af8abd.jpg">
    <img id="EX2-Walkwayspic" class="thumbs" src="http://i101.photobucket.com/albums/m55/ladybytesjdb/ACsite/EX2_Walkwayspic_zpsd79a1a2a.jpg">              

    <!--first row of caption-->
    <div class="EX2-Pooltxt"></div>
    <div class="EX2-Patiostxt"></div>
    <div class="EX2-Stairstxt"></div>
    <div class="EX2-Walkwaystxt"></div>
    </div><!--End of thumbs-->
  </div><!-- End of EX2thumbnailpicsbox-->
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#EX2-Poolspic").hover(
    function () {
    $("#myframe").attr("src", "http://s101.photobucket.com/user/ladybytesjdb/slideshow/ACsite");
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#EX2contentwrapper {
    width: 2000px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#sliderContainer{
    background-color: #989898;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
}
#EX2thumbnailpicsbox {
    width: 1066px;
    height: 539px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    z-index: 99;
}

#thumbs {
    width: 1066px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#EX2-Poolspic {
    width: 274px;
    height: 229px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}

#EX2-Patiospic {
    width: 261px;
    height: 229px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#EX2-Stairspic {
    width: 260px;
    height: 229px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#EX2-Walkwayspic {
    width: 271px;
    height: 229px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#EX2-Pooltxt {
    width: 274px;
    height: 31px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.EX2-Patiostxt {
    width: 261px;
    height: 31px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.EX2-Stairstxt {
    width: 260px;
    height: 31px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.EX2-Walkwaystxt {
    width: 271px;
    height: 31px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/58huLuzf/2/)**

Comment: I added and replaced code into mine and I can't seem to get it to work or display the slider. I am not sure if need another div container to hold the sliderContainer.

Comment: please post your slider and Html code to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and comment the link here. so that I can look into your code and guide you properly.

Comment: I added my code into Fiddle and was able to get it to show text in the sliderContainer. I need to place my html sliders in this container instead of just the text. I'm stuck and I do not know how to "change my div content to slider here". Do I have to add a <a href> link to all my html sliders(EXPoolsSlider,EXPatiosSlider,EXStairsSlider,EXWalkwaysSlider) into the 'thumbs' div? http://jsfiddle.net/MMB279/58huLuzf/

Comment: I modified your code a bit and made a working slider for you. Answer is updated and also the demo link. You can also see it by [clicking here](http://jsfiddle.net/58huLuzf/1/)

Comment: Please mark as answer, as a reward, if it helped you.

Comment: That works for static images, do I have to have an active .html file to have my sliders work? I have multiple .html sliders that play their own slideshow of 2 - 3 images. I replaced the 'src' with  the path of my .html file from my folder but it is not displaying. Am I missing something? What you showed me works for only one image. I want each of my thumbs to display their own sliders. Thank you for your help but that still does not solve my issue..:-(

Comment: please post your `slider html` code to Fiddle n comment here the link. I can't really help without seeing the slider code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MMB279/58huLuzf/ I use the jquery.cycle.all.js for the slider

Comment: As far as I understood from what you told me, I'm sorry I couldn't completely understand, you can show each slider in an `iFrame` control. On the `onhover` of thumbnail you can change `src` of that `iFrame`. I have made a demo with **one slider only** from the link you provided. See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/58huLuzf/2/). When you'll hover on `first` thumbnail the div will change to a slider after loading.

Comment: I believe I need to use an active url to make this work. Right now they are not working and that is probably the reason why I'm not seeing my results. But with all you're help, you have pointed me to the right direction. THANK YOU sooooo much for your patience!